# Is there an equivalent to the Apache “Alias” command in Django?

Tags: django

I have the following in the .htaccess file of a Django project directory

```
Alias ^$ app/misc/
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing just using Django (say in the urlconf).

The point of the Alias is that the page actually returned to the user is app/misc/default.html,  and all the files that default.html references are in that same directory, which would have to be appended to each file reference in default.html without the alias.  Maybe this is commonplace.

Edit:
Don't know what I could have been missing the above doesn't even work.

Comment: See: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: That's for the development version of Django. Anyway, if you know specifically in there where it points out how to do what I want that would be great. During development, I was using django.views.static.serve, which is Django's own static file server for testing purposes only. But I found out on deployment the first time you don't have to do anything special for static files for Apache. Anyway, I don't want to do something complicated if I can accomplish it with one line in .htaccess. But I would rather do it in Django if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long-shot and maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. As long as your anchors in default.html are defined as, say, `<a href="link.html">link</a>` or `<a href="./link.html">link</a>` they will be relative to `/app/misc/` in this case. However, if you prefix them with a slash like `<a href="/link.html">link</a>` they will be relative to the root of your web server.

Is that helping you at all?